# I have suppressed warnings in knitr output but the warnings do not show up in the Rmarkdown console as expected. How do I view these?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using Knitr and rmarkdown. I have suppressed warnings in the .pdf output and then typically the warnings are listed in the rmarkdown console. However, in the case of one specific report, instead of getting the warnings listed in the rmarkdown console, I get this message: There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them). Where do I write this warnings() code to see the list of warnings?

I have tried adding warnings() at the bottom of my rmarkdown document but the output is: NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an .rmd file, you will need to knit that file through an r script to produce the errors in the console, becuase .rmd files use unique consoles for each R call. Try this:

```
setwd("C:/blah/blah")
knitr::knit("blah.Rmd")
warnings()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you type `warnings()` in the console it will show you that last 15. The console in this environment works predominately the same way that it does in a script. Anything you type is run line, by line, but you are working in the same global environment.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I unfortunately tried that and when I type warnings() in the console it returns NULL in the same way it returns NULL when I add it to my markdown document.

Comment: How odd...have you tried switching to a 'script' screen immediately and running it in the console there? I have found what lives in the global memory I can pull from a script to markdown and vice versa. It is worth a try. Just make sure there is no gc() anywhere in your markdown and you run nothing before switching back to the script pane.