# view warnings in RStudio after rendering an R Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I often knit R Markdown documents in RStudio. That is, I click the "Knit" icon or use a keyboard shortcut to have my documents rendered by `rmarkdown::render()`. Sometimes, when I do so, the output in the R Markdown pane concludes with a message like

```
Output created: myDoc.html
There were 15 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

How can I view these warnings? I would like to see them in the output to the R Markdown pane, or by typing `warnings()` in the console -- or ideally, in both ways.

Of course, I could see them if I ran `rmarkdown::render('myDoc.Rmd')` in the console, instead of using the RStudio shortcuts. But that approach is inconvenient. I also don't want to modify options for individual code chunks.

A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474305/i-have-suppressed-warnings-in-knitr-output-but-the-warnings-do-not-show-up-in-th) came up about four years ago, but no solutions were posted.

Comment: You can run the code chunks and see what warnings message pop up. The shortcuts Ctrl+Alt+N or Cmd+Option+N will do this.

Comment: This is not working :/

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the way to see them is by typing `warnings()`:

```
val <- sqrt(-1)

warnings()

# Warning message:
# In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced
```

Perhaps you had the `quiet=TRUE` flag set when running `rmarkdown::render()`, and that affected things. If it isn't already, make sure it's `FALSE`, and then trying `warnings()` again.